# How to automate multiple iOS apps in a single session

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I am trying to run automation on multiple iOS apps. Beside this  out of the 2 apps , one app is not created by me. It is a third party app downloaded from app store would i be able to execute the command on that third party app(as it is not signed by development profile). It would be great help if anybody could suggest me some tools that can be used for automating multiple iOS apps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run `instruments` on multiple apps in the same session.  You would have to launch a new instance of `instruments` each time your context switched.

In the simulator, this is currently impossible as instruments closes the app its automating when the automation completes.